# How to join same table twice using PXSelectJoinOrderBy

Tags: sql, acumatica

I am trying to create view using PXSelectJoinOrderBy for the following SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM INVENTORYITEM II
LEFT JOIN INItemXRef X1 ON II.InventoryID = X1.InventoryID AND 
X1.AlternateType = '0VPN' LEFT JOIN INItemXRef X2 ON II.InventoryID = X1.InventoryID AND
X2.AlternateType = '0CPN'
```

I have used the following statement to join INItemXRef table once and it is working fine.

```
public PXSelectJoinOrderBy<InventoryItem, LeftJoin<INItemXRef, On<INItemXRef.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>, OrderBy<Asc<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>> FilteredItems;
```

How to   join INItemXRef  again with different alias?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain the result you want by creating 2 class that inherit the class INItemXRef and using them in the bql query.

```
public PXSelectJoinOrderBy<InventoryItem,
    LeftJoin<VendorINItemXRef, 
        On<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
            Equal<VendorINItemXRef.inventoryID>,
            And<VendorINItemXRef.alternateType,
                Equal<string_0VPN>>>,
    LeftJoin<CustomerINItemXRef,
        On<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
            Equal<CustomerINItemXRef.inventoryID>,
            And<CustomerINItemXRef.alternateType,
                Equal<string_0CPN>>>>>,
    OrderBy<Asc<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>> FilteredItems;

public class VendorINItemXRef : INItemXRef
{
    public new class inventoryID : IBqlField{}
    public new class alternateType : IBqlField{}
}

public class CustomerINItemXRef : INItemXRef
{
    public new class inventoryID : IBqlField { }
    public new class alternateType : IBqlField { }
}
```

You also need to override the parameters that will be used for the comparison so the system can bound them.

For additional information you can also check this question :
[Acumatica BQL Query with the same table more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368268/acumatica-bql-query-with-the-same-table-more-than-once).

Comment: +1 for referring to another Acumatica question on StackOverflow! There are other ways to achieve the same result, such as using a PXProjection or a PXDBScalar, but it is by far the most simple way to do it. Thanks Samuel!